# Modifying form's properties from an external function c#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, function, reference

I'm currently working on a C# Windows Forms Project.

I have 3 Windows Forms - FormA, FormB, FormC and an external class File called Tools.

What I want is to create a function which can modify properties on each form when called. Ι feel that -this- should be passed and used, as argument in my function.

This is Tools.cs Code:

```
    public class Tools
    {
       public static void FullScreenMode(/*Should Pass a form's instance?*/) 
       {
           FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
           WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
           Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
           this.Location = screen.Bounds.Location;
       }
    }
```

Until now when I build the project I get the following errors

> Error 5   'System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'    C:\Users\AGDS\Dropbox\UniPi\5th\User Experience\Smart City\SmartCity\SmartCity\Tools.cs 72  13  SmartCity
>
> Error 6   The name 'WindowState' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\AGDS\Dropbox\UniPi\5th\User Experience\Smart City\SmartCity\SmartCity\Tools.cs 73  13  SmartCity
>
> Error 7   Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer    C:\Users\AGDS\Dropbox\UniPi\5th\User Experience\Smart City\SmartCity\SmartCity\Tools.cs 75  13  SmartCity

Comment: The error you've found appeared because, as the error suggest, are using FormBorderStyle as variable, you should use it so: this.FormBorderStyle

Answer (score 0):

```
          public class Tools
              {
             public static void FullScreenMode(Form fr) 
            {
                   fr.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                   fr.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                    fr.Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
                    fr.Location = screen.Bounds.Location;


              }
                   }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you like helper-type approach - try next code

```cs
public static class Tools
{
    public static void FullScreenMode(this Form form)
    {
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
        form.Location = screen.Bounds.Location;
    }
}
```

and use it:

- Inside form:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FullScreenMode();
}
```

- Outside form (ie. other form):

```cs
// some way to access other form...
public Form OtherForm { get; set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OtherForm.FullScreenMode();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use **this** in **static** method.

**FormBorderStyle** and **WindowState** is a type, you cannot assign value to it. You should pass the Forms reference to this function to get the job done.

```
public class Tools
{
    public static void FullScreenMode(Form @this)
    {
        @this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        @this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
        @this.Location = screen.Bounds.Location;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are wrong, he is doing it in separated class at all. Static doesn't matter here.

Comment: check the error thrown. How could you use this in static methid @MadOX?

Comment: he is trying to use this as Form in separated class, even removing static will not change anything, cause Tools class has no Location member.

Comment: Then his question is wrong. He has declared static method on only Tools class according to his post.

Comment: @MadOX do you say that the compiler throws a wrong error?

Comment: Im saying that solving that THIS will not make OP closer to solution of even tiny bit. It will still not compile, with error: Location is not a member of Tools.And still 3 compilation errors.

Comment: I didn't say it solves the problem I pointed out the mistakes he has done. Stackoverflow is there for both to point out their mistakes and solve their problems